# File not found error for .txt file but not .m3u?

Tags: java, file, exception, io, fileinputstream

I'm testing some java code I'm working on for a school project and I'm unable to create a new file representing a txt file but am able to make one for an .m3u file. For example, the following throws a FileNotFound exception:

```
java.io.FileInputStream inputFile;
    try
    {
        File file = new File("consoledata1.txt");
        inputFile = new FileInputStream( file );
        MixTapeConsole mtc = new MixTapeConsole(inputFile);
    }
    catch( Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Could not find file");
        fail("File not found.");
    }
```

But this does not:

```
MixTapeModel mtm = new MixTapeModel();
mtm.loadM3U( new java.io.File("MilesDavis.m3u"));
```

Both files are in the file directory and confirmed (by printing the absolute path) that java is looking in the correct place for both. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to open the m3u file in the same block as you opened the consoledata? Just exchange the filename and see what hapens.

Comment: Are you using the correct case for the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting an absolute path for a file does not mean it exists!  E.G.

#### Source

```
import java.io.File;

public class PathTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("DoesNotExist.txt");
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println(file.exists());
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
I:\projects\eclipse\Test\DoesNotExist.txt
false
```

### Conclusion

The file is either not where you think it is, or not spelled with the correct case.

Answer (score 0):

try with
    File file = new File("someFileName.txt");
    file.createNewFile()

check whether the someFileName.txt file is there in your folder or some where else.